# Calling lex/yacc from a separate program

Tags: bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I've been reading up on lex/yacc. The books and examples are not hard to follow. In fact, the whole concept is clear as a bell. With one exception. Lex/yacc seem to generate standalone programs. What if I wanted to call them as a parser function? Yacc seems to generate a main function, so how would I call from my own without conflicts.

I'm also unclear at this point how they operate on file input. I'm okay with grabbing a line from a file and sending it to the parser, but what if your parser is looking for a multi-line structure like a block enclosed in braces?

I realize I'm being stupid about both of these, but any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

input to the lexx / yacc combo is via a FILE * called yyin.

this defaults to stdin - trawl around lex.yy.c to find it

if you assign a FILE * to yyin, the lexer will read from that file, you do something like

yyin = fopen ("parseme", "rt");

before the call to yyparse(), typically in your main().

Answer (score 2):

Both programs generate the `yylex()` and `yyparse()` functions, but none of them generates a main function. You have to add your own `main()` function somewhere. Many tutorials place them into the .l or .y file, but you are free to place them where ever you want.